# How can extract Custom Property value from lambda expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, reflection

I have the following class definition

## Person.cs

```
class Person {

  [Column("first_name")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [Column("last_name")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote an HTML Helper extension to extract the `ColumnAttribute` value from a given instance. However, it does not work as I expect.

Here is what I tried:

## Index.cshtml

```
@model Person
<p>ColumnName is @Html.ColumnNameFor( model => model.FirstName )</p>
```

## HtmlExtensions.cs (public static class)

```
public static string ColumnNameFor<T, P>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<Func<T, P>> expression)
{
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

    // this line causes a runtime error:
    //  Sequence contains no elements
    var attr = (ColumnAttribute)metadata.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false).First();
            
  return attr.Name;    // ColumnAttribute stores the value in .Name
}
```

For the record, I am able to extract the value using `GetCustomAttributes`, provided that I pass a reference to the property, which I think will make the code in the View look very different from the built in ASP MVC code for `Html.TextBoxFor` and `Html.DisplayFor`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @benuto for his answer, I was able to find out how I could extract any required custom attribute or property using `MemeberExpress`. I wanted the answer to help others, so I made a working example. Bear in mind that you will need to check if the object does have a custom property or not, to avoid crashing when accessing `FirstOrDefault().Name`.

```
 public static string ColumnNameFor<T, P>( this HtmlHelper<T> helper, 
                                           Expression<Func<T, P>> expression)
 {
      var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

      MemberExpression me = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

      var cp = (ColumnAttribute)me
                  .Member
                  .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false)
                  .FirstOrDefault();

      return (cp == null) ? null : cp.Name;
 }
```